# How to add custom request/response processing component in Jersey application chain

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I have a REST application with Jersey framework.Now what i want to do is to reformat every request comes to a specific resource by adding new request header and encode certain fields in to response sent back to client.

I want to do this for every resource in my application, so i want to know that if there is a way to add custom request/response processing components into REST application request processing chain ?

I tried with LoggingFilter and some other context resolver classes but couldn't get it at all !

Can i do this with with servlet Filter chain ? But i would prefer to do it by Jersey way if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to make use of the filters and interceptors that Jersey provides. Documentation is [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html)